# How to run sorbet typecheck on rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, sorbet

I notice that by default, `srb init` etc doesn't put # typed flag on rake tasks. However, on VSCode, it does show error (eg missing constant) on rake task.

I've tried to add `# typed: true` to rake tasks but it would immediately show errors like "namespace is not available in Root". Have anyone tried to typecheck your rake tasks? What's the set up to do that?

Comment: Do you have an example `Rakefile` or rake task? I'm happy to look at a failing example in more detail.

Comment: It's any rake task really. The error is shown for "namespace:" command which is the first line in the rake task. I'll send you a sample on slack.

Comment: Yup, it's a problem for all the Rake tasks in my repos as well. I think it's just a situation where Sorbet doesn't know about the DSL of the Rake files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rake monkeypatches the global `main` object (i.e., top-level code) to extend their DSL:

```rb
# Extend the main object with the DSL commands. This allows top-level
# calls to task, etc. to work from a Rakefile without polluting the
# object inheritance tree.
self.extend Rake::DSL
```

→ [lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/80e00e2d59ea5b230f2f0416c387c0b57184f1ff/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb#L192-L195)

Sorbet cannot model that a single instance of an object (in this case `main`) has a different inheritance hierarchy than that instance's class (in this case `Object`).

To get around this, we recommend refactoring the `Rakefile` to make a new class where the inheritance hierarchy is explicit:

```rb
# -- my_rake_tasks.rb --

# (1) Make a proper class inside a file with a *.rb extension
class MyRakeTasks
  # (2) Explicitly extend Rake::DSL in this class
  extend Rake::DSL

  # (3) Define tasks like normal:
  task :test do
    puts 'Testing...'
  end

  # ... more tasks ...
end

# -- Rakefile --

# (4) Require that file from the Rakefile
require_relative './my_rake_tasks'
```

---

Alternatively, we it's possible to write an RBI for `Object` that makes it appear to `extend Rake::DSL`. This RBI would be **mostly wrong**: not all instances of `Object` have this `extend`, only one does. We **DO NOT** suggest this approach because it could make it look like some code type checks even though methods like `task` and `namespace` are not defined. If you wanted to do this anyways, you can write this RBI file for `Object`:

```rb
# -- object.rbi --

# Warning!! Monkeypatches all Object's everywhere!
class Object
  extend Rake::DSL
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A much better way IMO is to just tell Sorbet what Rake is doing.

At some point [Rake extends Object](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb#L195) like so:

```rb
# Extend the main object with the DSL commands. This allows top-level
# calls to task, etc. to work from a Rakefile without polluting the
# object inheritance tree.
self.extend Rake::DSL
```

In each rake file you can just tell Sorbet that this is happening.

```rb
# -- lib/tasks/example.rake --

# typed: true

T.bind(self, T.all(Rake::DSL, Object))

namespace "rake_task" do
  desc "do a thing"
  task do_it: :environment do
    # rake task
  end
end
```

The only other thing to do is to tell sorbet's typechecker to look at .rake files. By default it only looks at .ruby and .rbi files. But you can tell it to also look at .rake files.

```
# -- sorbet/config --

--dir
.

--allowed-extension=.rb
--allowed-extension=.rbi
--allowed-extension=.rake
```